# Laravel controller getting results based on parameter including relationship results

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I am trying to learn to improve my coding on a daily basis and this is one of the first times I am posting on here, so bear with me.

I have two models, a Payment and an Expense model. A `payment` hasMany `expenses`. In a table I am showing all payments, including the sum of all expenses for each payment. Now I would like to update the data based on a URL parameter `type`. A `payment` can have a type of `contract`, `subscription` or `payment_plan`.

In my controller I am doing the following to achieve this:

```
public function index(Request $request)
{
    $type = $request->input('type') ?? null;
    $query = auth()->user()->payments()->where('status', 'active'); // Only query active payments

    if ($type !== null)
    {
        $query->where('type', $type);
    }

    $count = $query->count(); // The total count of active payments
    $amount = $query->sum('amount'); // The total amount of all active payments
    $paid = $query->withSum('expenses', 'amount')->get(); // Getting all related expenses for each payment, including the sum of the amount of all those expenses
    $paid = $paid->sum('expenses_sum_amount'); // Getting the total sum
    $remaining = $amount - $paid; // The remaining amount that has to be paid

    return view('payments.index')
        ->withPaymentNumber($count)
        ->withPaymentAmount($amount)
        ->withPaymentPaid($paid)
        ->withPaymentRemaining($remaining);
}
```

I know this code can be improved alot upon, and I would love to see other people's visions on how they would achieve this.

Answer (score 4):

Using [eloquent when(](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/queries#conditional-clauses)) function the above code would be cleaner, especially if you add more filters in the future.

I am not sure what version of laravel you are using, but Request injection probably can be replaced by the request() function.

```
public function index() {
    $query = auth()->user()->payments()
        ->where('status', 'active') // Only query active payments
        ->when(request('type') !== null, function ($query) {
            return $query->where('type', request('type'));
        });

    $count = $query->count(); // The total count of active payments
    $amount = $query->sum('amount'); // The total amount of all active payments
    $paid = $query->withSum('expenses', 'amount')->get(); // Getting all related expenses for each payment, including the sum of the amount of all those expenses
    $paid = $paid->sum('expenses_sum_amount'); // Getting the total sum
    $remaining = $amount - $paid; // The remaining amount that has to be paid

    return view('payments.index')
        ->withPaymentNumber($count)
        ->withPaymentAmount($amount)
        ->withPaymentPaid($paid)
        ->withPaymentRemaining($remaining);
}
```